# Is there a way to view last commit for selected line in IntelliJ?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, ide

I just switched from Visual Studio Code to IntelliJ for Java development. Is there any way for IntelliJ to show last commit information on the current selected line? I used this a lot in VSCode since we have multiple teams working on the same project.

[image: 1]

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such feature in IDE, but there is a feature request, please see and vote:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-190536

But as @SwissCodeMen mentioned, such a feature can be enabled by a plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same like GitLens from Visual Studio Code can the Jetbrains [*GitToolBox*](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox).

You must install the plugin on your IntelliJ. [Managing plugins in IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins).

[image]

After them, you can toggle it in on **Settings** -> **Other Settings** -> **GitToolBox Global** or **GitToolBox Project** (if you only want to configure per project)

[image]